# Laravel 8 Changes to Route::group method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am currently doing an upgrade from Laravel 7 to 8, and then from 8 to 9. I am getting this error when running composer update:

```
Array to string conversion

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteFileRegistrar.php:35
     31▕     public function register($routes)
     32▕     {
     33▕         $router = $this->router;
     34▕ 
  ➜  35▕         require $routes;
     36▕     }
     37▕ }
     38▕ 

      +4 vendor frames 
  5   routes/api/features.php:21
```

Something seems to have changed between versions with the group function. Here is the routes file:

```
Route::prefix('features')->middleware('api', 'admin')->group([ [HasFeature::feature(Features::featureFlags)]], function () {
    Route::post('', FeatureFlagController::method('createFeature'));
    Route::patch('/{uuid}/client/{client_id}', FeatureFlagController::method('addClientToFeature'));
    Route::delete('/{uuid}/client/{client_id}', FeatureFlagController::method('removeClientFromFeature'));
    Route::get('{client_id?}', FeatureFlagController::method('getAllFeatures'));
    Route::post('/clear/{client_id?}', FeatureFlagController::method('clearFeatureCache'));
    Route::patch('{uuid}', FeatureFlagController::method('updateFeature'));
    Route::get('{uuid}', FeatureFlagController::method('getFeature'));
});
```

The issue appears to be with the group function, looks like an array with another array is being passed in. This is a codebase that is still rather new to me, so I'm trying to figure out what is happening.

Here is the middleware file of HasFeature:

```
<?php

namespace App\FeatureFlags\Middleware;

use App\Facades\Client;
use Closure;

class HasFeature
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $featureKey = null)
    {
        if (!Client::hasFeature($featureKey)) {
            abort('403', "Forbidden");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    public static function feature(String $feature)
    {
        return static::class . ":" . $feature;
    }
}
```

So it appears, that we are calling this static method `feature` within two arrays. I'm not sure 100% what is happening here, but it seems to be causing some issues with the Laravel 8 upgrade.

Does anyone know what the array within another array is doing as the first parameter in this route group method? And how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The signature of `group` function is `group(\Closure|string $callback)`, don't think it accepts two parameters or even an array. By the way what does `[ [HasFeature::feature(Features::featureFlags)]]` output?

Answer (score 0):

[This commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/315a46a0ee284920ff2de3a34e5de09ebf88923f?diff=unified) can be helpful, I assume that for newer Laravel version this code:

```
$router = $this;

require $routes;
```

was changed to this:

```
(new RouteFileRegistrar($this))->register($routes);
```